# Android Facebook SDK sign on issue

Tags: android, facebook

So i followed [this tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-2) to set up the android facebook sdk in my app i already have built. I now have all the files the tutorial says to build and everything shows no errors. Now i want to be able to set my app so that when the user presses a button on the app it brings them to the Facebook sign on page. I tried using this code but it doesnt work, the app crashes and i get these errors in logcat.

Can anyone help me get this to work?

```
ImageButton facebook= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook);
        facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FBConnectionActivity.class);
                 startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); 

            }
            });
```

And these are the errors logcat gives me:

```
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.outfit.first/com.outfit.first.FBConnectionActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.outfit.first.FBConnectionActivity
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1680)
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3839)
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.outfit.first.FBConnectionActivity
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-10 22:10:57.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont try and start an activity using the FBConnectionActivity, instead in the acivity you want them to login on extend the FBConnectionActivity
eg:

```
public class myActivity extends FBconnectionActivity{.......
```

then in your onClickListener within myActivity(or whatever you've called it!) just call the setConnection() and getID() methods, this will then prompt the user to login via facebook. eg:

```
ImageButton facebook= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook);
facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        setConnection();
        getID();
    }
});
```

Note that this used a getID() method without the textView and progress bar that it in the tutorial, you can just add the following to you FBConnectionActivity class:

```
public void getID() {
    if (isSession()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "sessionValid");
        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new IDRequestListener());
    } else {
        // no logged in, so relogin
        Log.d(TAG, "sessionNOTValid, relogin");
        mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMS, new LoginDialogListener());
    }
}
```

Comment: I used that code and it works great except after I entered the user information the app crashes and logcat says something like this. I think i need to refocus the app on my main xml but i think there is more to the problem.  `07-12 16:27:22.214: WARN/InputManagerService(148): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@406b2308
07-12 16:27:22.254: WARN/ViewServer(148): Connection error: 
07-12 16:27:22.254: WARN/ViewServer(148): java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe `

Comment: Hmm strange! Are you trying to do anything else after you login? You can try moving the setConnection() method to outside & before the on click listener, but that shouldn't make a difference. The error your getting is caused by writing to a connection when the other end has already closed it.

Comment: I'll try that right now. My code was too long to repost in the question so i posted a new question with all of the code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671122/facebook-android-sdk-nullpointerexception. Maybe some of that information would be helpful.

Comment: I'll take a look just now for you. mark my answer to get this one off the unanswered list, in future you can just edit the question to (delete the old code + add the new code whilst putting a comment explaining that your edited the question)extend it rather than starting a new question.