# Facebook Android SDK NullPointerException

Tags: android, facebook

I followed this tutorial online to set up the facebook sdk for my android app. it works up until the user logs in and then i get this error in logcat when it crashes

```
07-12 16:59:29.783: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(556): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 16:59:29.783: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(556): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 16:59:29.783: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(556):     at com.outfit.first.FBConnectionActivity$IDRequestListener$1.run(FBConnectionActivity.java:129)
07-12 16:59:29.783: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(556):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-12 16:59:29.783: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(556):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-12 16:59:29.783: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(556):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-12 16:59:29.783: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(556):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3839)
07-12 16:59:29.783: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(556):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 16:59:29.783: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(556):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-12 16:59:29.783: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(556):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-12 16:59:29.783: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(556):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
07-12 16:59:29.783: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(556):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My entire code is bellow and I starred the lines that logcat says called the error, it is this line:

```
 username.setText("Welcome: " + name+"\n ID: "+id);
```

Can anyone help me figure out what im doing wrong? I feel like im so close to it working.

```
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.android.Util;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;

public abstract class FBConnectionActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String TAG = "FACEBOOK";
    private Facebook mFacebook;
    public static final String APP_ID = "IDHERE";
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    private static final String[] PERMS = new String[] { "read_stream" };
    private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    private Context mContext;

    private TextView username;
    private ProgressBar pb;

    public void setConnection() {
            mContext = this;
            mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
            mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
    }

    public void getID() {
        if (isSession()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "sessionValid");
            mAsyncRunner.request("me", new IDRequestListener());
        } else {
            // no logged in, so relogin
            Log.d(TAG, "sessionNOTValid, relogin");
            mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMS, new LoginDialogListener());
        }
    }

    public void getID(TextView txtUserName, ProgressBar progbar) {
            username = txtUserName;
            pb = progbar;
            if (isSession()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "sessionValid");
                    mAsyncRunner.request("me", new IDRequestListener());
            } else {
                    // no logged in, so relogin
                    Log.d(TAG, "sessionNOTValid, relogin");
                    mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMS, new LoginDialogListener());
            }
    }

    public boolean isSession() {
            sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
            String access_token = sharedPrefs.getString("access_token", "x");
            Long expires = sharedPrefs.getLong("access_expires", -1);
            Log.d(TAG, access_token);

            if (access_token != null && expires != -1) {
                    mFacebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
                    mFacebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
            }
            return mFacebook.isSessionValid();
    }

    private class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "LoginONComplete");
                    String token = mFacebook.getAccessToken();
                    long token_expires = mFacebook.getAccessExpires();
                    Log.d(TAG, "AccessToken: " + token);
                    Log.d(TAG, "AccessExpires: " + token_expires);
                    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
                    sharedPrefs.edit().putLong("access_expires", token_expires)
                                    .commit();
                    sharedPrefs.edit().putString("access_token", token).commit();
                    mAsyncRunner.request("me", new IDRequestListener());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "FacebookError: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "OnCancel");
            }
    }

    private class IDRequestListener implements RequestListener {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                    try {
                            Log.d(TAG, "IDRequestONComplete");
                            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);

                            final String id = json.getString("id");
                            final String name = json.getString("name");
                            FBConnectionActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                    //!!!line 129!!!        username.setText("Welcome: " + name+"\n ID: "+id);
                                            pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

                                    }
                            });
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
                    } catch (FacebookError e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "FacebookError: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                            Object state) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                            Object state) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "FacebookError: " + e.getMessage());
            }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
So this is the code in my activity that starts facebook from a button click:

```
ImageButton combine = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.CompressImg);
        combine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setConnection();
                getID();
                //createoneimage("final.png");          
            }
            });
```

And this is my main.java class which im honestly not sure what it does:

```
public class main extends FBConnectionActivity {
    private TextView txtUserName;
    private ProgressBar pbLogin;
    private Button btnLogin;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainfb);

    txtUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textFacebook);
    pbLogin = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressLogin);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            pbLogin.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                            setConnection();
                            getID(txtUserName, pbLogin);
                    }
            });
}
}
```

And finally this is my mainfb.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/textFacebook"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/welcome" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        <Button android:text="@string/enter" android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textFacebook"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="30dip"></Button>
        <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressLogin"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ProgressBar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT 2:
Since ive been working with this code ive realized that every time i use this code the first time i log in the app crashes and then the second time it logs in fine once it already has the fb user information saved. Bellow is the logcat error i get when it crashes. I'm not sure if its really working the second time because i dont get any errors but when i try to post to my fb wall it get errors then.

```
07-16 21:46:16.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 21:46:16.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 21:46:16.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at com.outfit.first.FBConnectionActivity$IDRequestListener$1.run(FBConnectionActivity.java:169)
07-16 21:46:16.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-16 21:46:16.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-16 21:46:16.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-16 21:46:16.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3839)
07-16 21:46:16.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 21:46:16.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-16 21:46:16.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-16 21:46:16.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
07-16 21:46:16.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: One possible issue is that the JSON you're getting back in the IDRequestListener does not contain a "name" object - which would result in the json.getString("name") returning null. What do you see in the logcat for the Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString()) line?

Comment: @Torid - The JSON does return a name object, its part of the standard response from facebook.
@Peter - Can you post the layout xml and code for the activity you implement this class in. There is no issue with the FBConnectionActivity class so your error must be coming from the other class.

Comment: Also can you mark in your code what line is number 129, i think its either username.setText(.... or pb.setVisibility(.... let me know which one.

Comment: Sorry it is username.setText. ill add it to the post right now

Comment: @Torid - one other thing is if it was due to the JSON not containing an object called name, it would throw a JSON Exception not a null pointer exception.

Comment: I believe that the JSONException is only thrown if the mapping does not exist - that is, if the JSON does not contain a name object. But I also believe you could still get a non-exception return from the json.getString("name") that was null if the JSON contained {"name":}. I know that the onComplete response string is supposed to contain  a"name" object, but have you checked what it is (via the log a few lines previously)?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so i think your issue is the that your `getID()` method uses the `IDRequestListener` which then is trying to set the username and id in a textview which is null because your calling `getID()` without passing the textview or progressbar as a parameter. So you have two options, firstly you could just add this function to your FBConnectionActivity class:

```
public void login(){
    if (!isSession()) {
        // no logged in, so relogin
        Log.d(TAG, "login");
        mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMS, new LoginDialogListener());
    }
}
```

Then rather than calling `getID()` just call `login()` - this way you will skip the `IDRequestListener` and hence there will be no null pointers. Or you could simply put a try/catch around the offending code:

```
try{
    username.setText("Welcome: " + name+"\n ID: "+id);
    pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

which would catch the exception and continue.

EDIT: infact looking through my answer i noticed that `loginDialogListener` uses the `IDRequestListener` so you either need to remove the calls to set the text view and progressbar or put the try/catch in!

Comment: When i pasted this in the second line pd = progDialog; comes up the with error "cannot be resoved". I think its suppoded to be "pb" not "pd" but that still comes up with the error.

Comment: sorry i was copy/pasting from a project i have that uses a dialog rather than a progress bar, i've also just edited the code so you dont need the pd = progDialog; line!

Comment: no worries - if you get stuck with anything else 'facebooky'- just post a comment here and link to you new question!

Comment: Hi im having a few problems, i just updated the question i was hoping you could help?